# Getting date from parse and displaying to a string Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, nsdate

So like the title says I am getting information from parse and displaying it but i can't figure out how to do this with a date. I need to cover it to a String to display in a label. Ive done a bit or research and understand I will need to use a date formatter but What I don't understand is where I put it and once its formatted how i display it. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var names = [String]()
var locations = [String]()
var dates = [NSDate]()
var imageFiles = [PFFile]()
var abouts = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
    refresh()

    PFGeoPoint.geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground { (geoPoint, error) -> Void in
        if let geoPoint = geoPoint {
            PFUser.currentUser()?["location"] = geoPoint
            PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackground()

    var getLocalPostsQuery = PFQuery(className: "publicPosts")
    if let latitude = PFUser.currentUser()!["location"].latitude {
        if let longitude = PFUser.currentUser()!["location"].longitude {
    getLocalPostsQuery.whereKey("searchLocation", withinGeoBoxFromSouthwest: PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude - 0.5, longitude: longitude - 0.5), toNortheast:  PFGeoPoint(latitude: latitude + 0.5, longitude: longitude + 0.5))
    getLocalPostsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {

                self.names.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.locations.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.abouts.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.dates.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
                self.imageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                for object in objects {

                    self.names.append(object["name"] as! String)
                    self.locations.append(object["location"] as! String)
                    self.dates.append(object["date"] as! String)
                    self.abouts.append(object["about"] as! String)
                    self.imageFiles.append(object["imageFile"] as! PFFile)
                    //self.attendings.append(object["attending"].count)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return names.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let LECell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LocalPostsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LocalPostsTableViewCell

    imageFiles[indexPath.row].getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (data, error) -> Void in
        if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

            LECell.postImage.image = downloadedImage
        }
    }


    LECell.postName.text = names[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postLocation.text = locations[indexPath.row]
    LECell.postDate.text = dates[indexPath.row]

    return LECell
}

let localPostsDetailSegue = "showLocalPostsDetailView"

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == localPostsDetailSegue {
        let detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! LocalPostsDetailViewController

        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let row = Int(indexPath.row)
            detailScene.name = names[row]
            detailScene.location = locations[row]
            detailScene.date = dates[row]
            detailScene.about = abouts[row]
            detailScene.photo = imageFiles[row]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily get string from NSDate and show it.

```
func getStringFromDate(date:NSDate)->String{

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, H:mm"
return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(yourDate) // yourDate is your parse date
}
```

you can make a category too.

Comment: Ok so where would I put this?

Comment: yourDate will be your parse date and you have to put where you want to assign text to your label because this func will give you String from Date

Comment: So I would put it in, for object in objects? Sorry I just really don't understand how to assign it once I have the string

Comment: First of all you have to change this line in your code self.dates.append(object["date"] as! String) to self.dates.append(object["date"] as! Date) and then in cellforRowatIndexPath you can change it to LECell.postDate.text = self. getStringFromDate(dates[indexPath.row]). will assign it to your cell label

Comment: Awesome I got it from here! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

```
 func getFormattedDate(string: String) -> String{


 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss +zzzz" // 2017-04-20T09:40:30+0000
        let formateDate = dateFormatter.date(from: string)!
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: formateDate)
        }
    let CreatedDates = "\(Date.getFormattedDate(string: "\(records["creationDate"]!)"))"
print("Date : \(CreatedDates)")
        //OutPut 
         20-04-2017
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanations. Raw code answers are not very helpful in general.

Comment: why ? what problem?

Comment: As I've said - "raw code answers are not very helpful *in general*". You could make your answer helpful to more people if you've explained your code. Beginners, for example, will be grateful. Also, it's just a good practice to explain why and how does your answer address the problem from the question.